# Usar una ruta absoluta

Tags: python, rutas

quisiera saber como hago para generar archivos siempre en la misma ruta, independiente del lugar donde este ejecutando código.

```
r = Path("C:", "/", "BBDD")
exist = os.path.exists(r)
print(exist)
False
```

Comment: Explica algo más qué es lo que debería hacer ese código. ¿Acaso existe `"C:\BBDD"`?

Comment: Lo que has hecho ya debería servir para lo que dices, pues estás especificando una ruta absoulta. Otra cosa es que no parece buena idea andar escribiendo ficheros en la carpeta raiz de C:. Mejor usas la carpeta del usuario, la cual puedes obtener con `Path.home()`.

Comment: muchas gracias,me pondre a investigar mas a fondo la libreria path c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```py
path = 'C:/BBDD/'

with open(path+'nombre_del_archivo.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Archivo creado')
```

En resumidas cuentas, crea un archivo con `with open() as f:` en la ruta especificada, con el nombre especificado, y le metemos el contenido que este dentro de `f.write()`.

La opción `'w'` de la función `open()` indica que en caso de que el archivo no exista lo creará, y si existe sobreescribirá todo el contenido con el nuevo contenido. También existen otras opciones como:

- `'a'`: Creará el archivo si no existe y si existe, añadirá el contenido al final de este.
- `'x'`: Creará el archivo si no existe, y si existe retorna un error.